# n objects, a value for each combination of two objects, find minimum value for each object in R

Tags: r, dplyr, qgis

I want to find the minimum value associated with an object out of a dataframe. The dataframe contains two columns representing all combinations of the objects and a value-column for each combination. It looks like this:

```
     id_A        id_B     dist
     206         208 2385.5096
     207         208  467.8890
     207         209  576.4631
...
     208         209  1081.539
     208         210  8214.439
...
```

I tried the following recommended `dplyr` functions:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id_A) %>% 
 slice(which.min(dist))
```

But it creates not the desired output:

```
id_A        id_B      dist
...
207         208       467.8890
208         209       1081.5393
...
```

Note that for id 208 the combination with id 207 has the lowest value, but is not associated to id 208 (when it is in the `grouped_by` column).

I wrote a function doing this right, but since I got many entries it is way to slow. Its a loop subsetting the data by all entries containing a specific id and then finds the minimum within that subset and associates that value with that id.

Do you have an idea, how to make that fast e.g. using `dplyr`.

Comment: *I am a stack overflow newbie, any suggestions on how to improve this entry are welcome. If i missed a existing post on this, I am very sorry.*

Comment: 'slice' should work for this. It is better to have a complete self-contained example. We cannot see `207` in the example, so there is no way to tell exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: done. problem then is, that the dataframe only contains one entry per combination?

Comment: In base R, `df[as.logical(ave(df$dist, df$id_A, FUN = function(x) x == min(x))),]` should work.

Comment: The `dplyr` function and the one suggested by Imo will work, when the we add the dataframe with id_A and id_B column interchanged to the original dataframe. So that, within a id_A x id_B matrix all entries are filled and not only one diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue boils down to needing a long (rather than wide) data format. First, here are some reproducible data (using the pipe from `dplyr`):

```
df <-
  LETTERS[1:4] %>%
  combn(2) %>%
  t %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(val = 1:n()) %>%
  setNames( c("id_A", "id_B", "dist") )
```

gives:

```
  id_A id_B dist
1    A    B    1
2    A    C    2
3    A    D    3
4    B    C    4
5    B    D    5
6    C    D    6
```

What we want is a pair of columns giving matching each category with the distance from its row. For this, I am using `gather` from `tidyr`. It creates new columns telling us which column the data came from and what value that held. Here, we are telling it to pull from columns `id_A` and `id_B` to give us the category for each ID entry (it then duplicates the `dist` column as necessary)

```
df %>%
  gather(whichID, Category, id_A, id_B)
```

Gives

```
   dist whichID Category
1     1    id_A        A
2     2    id_A        A
3     3    id_A        A
4     4    id_A        B
5     5    id_A        B
6     6    id_A        C
7     1    id_B        B
8     2    id_B        C
9     3    id_B        D
10    4    id_B        C
11    5    id_B        D
12    6    id_B        D
```

We can then pass *that* data.frame to `group_by` and then use `summarise` to give us whatever information we wanted. I know that you didn't ask for the max, but I am including it just to show the general syntax you can use to get whatever type of result you want:

```
df %>%
  gather(whichID, Category, id_A, id_B) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(minDist = min(dist)
            , maxDist = max(dist))
```

Returns:

```
  Category minDist maxDist
     <chr>   <int>   <int>
1        A       1       3
2        B       1       5
3        C       2       6
4        D       3       6
```

I just looked at the question and realized that you wanted to also display *which* comparison had the minimum value. Here is an approach that does that by tracking an index of the match (so that it is replicated when `gather`ing) and then pulls the correct row from the original `df` and pastes together the two comparison values:

```
df %>%
  mutate(whichComparison = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(whichID, Category, id_A, id_B) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(minDist = min(dist)
            , whichMin = whichComparison[which.min(dist)]
            , maxDist = max(dist)
            , whichMax = whichComparison[which.max(dist)]) %>%
  mutate(
    minComp = sapply(whichMin, function(x){
      paste(df[x, "id_A"], df[x, "id_B"], sep = " vs " )})
    , maxComp = sapply(whichMax, function(x){
      paste(df[x, "id_A"], df[x, "id_B"], sep = " vs " )})
  )
```

returns

```
  Category minDist whichMin maxDist whichMax minComp maxComp
     <chr>   <int>    <int>   <int>    <int>   <chr>   <chr>
1        A       1        1       3        3  A vs B  A vs D
2        B       1        1       5        5  A vs B  B vs D
3        C       2        2       6        6  A vs C  C vs D
4        D       3        3       6        6  A vs D  C vs D
```

If you really want a single column giving which comparison gave the min value (and the max, in my output), you can instead use the index to pull both the `id_A` and `id_B` from the original `df`, knock out the one that matches the Category of interest, then use `use_first_valid_of` from the package `janitor` to grab just the one you are interested in. Because this generated a large number of intermediate columns, I am using `select` to clean things back up:

```
df %>%
  mutate(whichComparison = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(whichID, Category, id_A, id_B) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(minDist = min(dist)
            , maxDist = max(dist)
            , whichMin = whichComparison[which.min(dist)]
            , whichMax = whichComparison[which.max(dist)]) %>%
  mutate(
    minA = df$id_A[whichMin]
    , minB = df$id_B[whichMin]
    , maxA = df$id_A[whichMax]
    , maxB = df$id_B[whichMax]
  ) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == Category, NA, as.character(.)) )
              , minA:maxB) %>%
  mutate(minComp = use_first_valid_of(minA, minB)
         , maxComp = use_first_valid_of(maxA, maxB)) %>%
  select(-(whichMin:maxB))
```

returns:

```
  Category minDist maxDist minComp maxComp
     <chr>   <int>   <int>   <chr>   <chr>
1        A       1       3       B       D
2        B       1       5       A       D
3        C       2       6       A       D
4        D       3       6       A       C
```

An alternative approach is to first convert the distance pairs to a matrix. Here, I first duplicate the comparisons in the reverse order to ensure that the matrix is complete (using `tidyr` to `spread`):

```
bind_rows(
  df
  , rename(df, id_A = id_B, id_B = id_A)
) %>%
  spread(id_B, dist)
```

returns:

```
  id_A  A  B  C  D
1    A NA  1  2  3
2    B  1 NA  4  5
3    C  2  4 NA  6
4    D  3  5  6 NA
```

Then, we just apply across rows much like we would if we working from a distance matrix (which may be where your data actually started):

```
bind_rows(
  df
  , rename(df, id_A = id_B, id_B = id_A)
) %>%
  spread(id_B, dist) %>%
  mutate(
    minDist = apply(as.matrix(.[, -1]), 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
    , minComp = names(.)[apply(as.matrix(.[, -1]), 1, which.min) + 1]
    , maxDist = apply(as.matrix(.[, -1]), 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
    , maxComp = names(.)[apply(as.matrix(.[, -1]), 1, which.max) + 1]
  ) %>%
  select(Category = `id_A`
         , minDist:maxComp)
```

returns:

```
  Category minDist minComp maxDist maxComp
1        A       1       B       3       D
2        B       1       A       5       D
3        C       2       A       6       D
4        D       3       A       6       C
```